# vim, how to search text and prepend new line before searched line

Tags: vim

```
Input :

<Action name="Compile" />
<Action name="Debug" />


Ouput:

<Action name="Parse" />
<Action name="Compile" />
<Action name="Debug" />
```

Using `vim`, how can i search for line starts contains word "Compile" and prepend the line with another line ?

I tired `:%s` but it is not replacing the entire line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it the Prince Goulash's way but…

```
:%s/^.*Compile/<Action name="Parse" \/>\r&

^.*Compile                     " matches everything from the first char on the line 
                               " up to and including 'Compile'
<Action name="Parse" \/>\r&    " replaces the match with the new desired line,
                               " followed by a newline, followed by the match
```

or the *very* elegant…

```
:g/Compile/t-|s//Parse

:g/Compile/t-                  " copies the matching line above itself
:s//Parse                      " substitutes the last search pattern with 'Parse'
                               " on that new line
```

Comment: with :%s and /gc i can now selectively replace items

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:g` command to search for lines, and then supply a `:normal!` command on each matched line:

```
:g/Compile/normal! O<Action name="Parse" />
```

The `!` ensures no user mappings are invoked in the `:normal` call.